# getting "signal SIGABT" when crypting CC_MD2 (similar to CC_SHA256) objective c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

i have a working code for creating CC_MD2 but for some reason after it finish creating the string i need i get a "signal SIGABT"

code:

```
NSString *key= @"secretKey";
NSString *data=@"message";

const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
const char *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
unsigned char cHMAC[CC_MD2_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
NSData *HMACData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
const unsigned char *buffer = (const unsigned char *)[HMACData bytes];
NSMutableString *HMAC = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:HMACData.length * 2];
for (int i = 0; i < HMACData.length; ++i){
    [HMAC appendFormat:@"%02x", buffer[i]];
}
NSLog(@"%@", HMAC);
```

Answer (score 0):

HMAC computes a MAC (message authentication code) by using a hashing function. MD2 is a hashing function. In theory HMAC can use it, but not using Common Crypto.

You are requesting a SHA1 HMAC, but passing a buffer of size `CC_MD2_DIGEST_LENGTH`, which is shorter.

The [hash algorithms available for HMAC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/CCHmac.3cc.html) are:

```
 kCCHmacAlgSHA1    - HMAC with SHA1 digest
 kCCHmacAlgMD5     - HMAC with MD5 digest
 kCCHmacAlgSHA256  - HMAC with SHA256 digest
 kCCHmacAlgSHA384  - HMAC with SHA384 digest
 kCCHmacAlgSHA224  - HMAC with SHA224 digest
 kCCHmacAlgSHA512  - HMAC with SHA512 digest
```

Do you actually mean to perform an HMAC, or do you mean to perform a hash?

Comment: im not sure about it, i was given a short c# code which im trying to figure out, as it seems that in the code they are using a  HMAC sha256 and somehow create a string which is 32 char long (which is what i need). in this code i made it to achive the right string.

*the c# code is:
BitConverter.ToString(new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.FromBase64String(key).ToString())).ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message))).Replace("-", string.Empty).Replace("\\", string.Empty).Trim().ToLower();

Comment: This C# has almost no relationship to the code you posted. Why are you passing MD2 and SHA1 options? Do you need an MD2? What are you actually doing? It is very dangerous to cut and paste crypto code. If you don't know what the code is doing, you need to talk to whoever has asked you to provide this and make sure you know what is required.

Comment: how do i compute a HMAC-SHA256? i seached all over for it and this is what i found

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension to a comment in Rob's answer.

Example code to compute HMAC-SGA256:

```
+ (NSData *)doHmacShar256:(NSData *)dataIn key:(NSData *)key {
    NSMutableData *macOut = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CCHmac( kCCHmacAlgSHA256,
           key.bytes,
           key.length,
           dataIn.bytes,
           dataIn.length,
           macOut.mutableBytes);

    return macOut;
}
```

Test:

```
NSData *dataIn = [@"Test Data" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *key    = [@"Test Key" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"dataIn:   %@", dataIn);
NSLog(@"key:      %@", key);

NSData *hmacData = [Test doHmacShar256:dataIn key:key];
NSLog(@"hmacData: %@", hmacData);

NSString *base64HmacShar256 = [hmacData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"base64HmacShar256: %@", base64HmacShar256);
```

Output:

```
dataIn:   54657374 20446174 61
key:      54657374 204b6579
hmacData: 74555a79 4d876aed ddb393fa 4cbcd925 312be549 eb4296e3 e52658b7 c598b5a8
base64HmacShar256: dFVaeU2Hau3ds5P6TLzZJTEr5UnrQpbj5SZYt8WYtag=
```

The class method was added to a class `Test`, add it to any class you like, perhaps the class you are using it in or a `Utility` class.

Comment: the data is recieved in bytes... i need it as a string. i tried to convert using utf8 the data to string and got null

Comment: You can not convert arbitrary data to a UTF-8 string, there are way to many data bytes that invalid UTF-8. That is why Base64 is used so often, it can represent any data bytes in an ASCII string. Just use `base64EncodedStringWithOptions`. `NSString *base64HmacShar256 = [hmacData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];`

Comment: your code works fine but i recieved a 28 char string (did [base64HmacShar256 length]), and i need to reieve 32 char string. i have a c# code which explain what i need in the last answer and im still not sure how to achive it

Comment: What you need and the methods you specified are impossible. SHS256 produces 256-bits (Yjat is why it is names SHA**256** it is 32-bytes. Base64 encoding of 32-bytes produces 44-bytes.

Comment: not sure i undertstand what you mean by "SHS256 produces 256-bits his is 32-bytes."

Comment: The output of SHA256 is 256-bits in size. Now you can ignore some of those bytes but that weakens the security.

Comment: how can i achive a 32 long string using HMAC?

Comment: `HmacAlgSHA256` produces 32 bytes. They are data, not characters, basically the security primitives work with data, not characters. BTW, see my updated code, in particular I made a mistake in the digest length, it should be (and now is) `CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH`. I re-used some code I had in the answer and missed changing that.

Comment: this is what i get from the c# code - d55d9fe22we0e2014443xvddab4cfe68, it removes the strings "/, +, -, ="

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70326/discussion-between-zaph-and-dante).

Comment: What does "it removes the strings "/, +, -, ="" mean? Perhaps add the C++ code to the question.

Comment: ill be waiting for you in the chat